# Angular failing on build, no module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

When building an angular cli it throws this error in the console after getting. Using node version 8.16.0

```
ERROR in ./src/app/core/services/body-resize.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@agm/core/utils/browser-globals' in 
/Users/admin/Desktop/<MY-DIRECTORY>/client/src/app/core/services
```

I have tried some enhancement packages. I followed the path and the file is there to be found. Just want to know if some have any input as to clear `Module not found error`.

Comment: do `npm install` seems you are dependend on agm module

Comment: @Reza I have done the npm install before trying to build

Comment: Can you please post your project's package.json file?